# php date + strtotime returns wrong date

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have some short dates in my POST variables.

If I do this:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($data->week as $week) {
    $date = $_POST['date'.($i+1)];
    echo $date;
    ...
    $i++;
 }
```

it returns the correct short dates e.g. 09.12. and 12.12.

If I do this

```
echo date('d.m.Y', strtotime($date));
```

it's returning 09.12.2013 (correct) and 09.12.2013 (incorrect, should be 12.12.2013).

Andy ideas?

Comment: Why don't you do `$date . "." . date(Y);`? it joins the day/month with the year

Comment: "09.12" is a terrifically ambiguous, incomplete, vague date. You cannot expect `strtotime` to know what you mean by that. Use any of the available methods to explicitly parse a date in a specified format (e.g. `DateTime::createFromFormat`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage for `strtotime` isn't correct. With such call it will apply *time* value for *current date*. It's like:

```
var_dump(date('d.m.Y H:i:s', strtotime('12.12')));//09.12.2013 12:12:00
var_dump(date('d.m.Y H:i:s', strtotime('11.12')));//09.12.2013 11:12:00
```

Instead you should use [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) API with it's [`createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat) method.

Answer (score 1):

Is something stopping you from using the **`DateTime`** class ?  ;)

Do something like this

```
<?php
$dt = '12.12';
$ctime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m', $dt);
echo $ndate= $ctime->format('d.m.Y'); // "prints" 12.12.2013
```